# Python Pandas two conditional dataframe groupby running sort

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

I'm looking for a way to run a two conditional pandas DataFrame groupby method. I have many logs to parse and I have the following single condition groupby method, but is there a way to have a two conditional groupby method?

```
DF[DF['Feature Enabled'] == 1].groupby([’Feature Active'])[['Value1','Value2']].mean()
```

Is there a way to print a running groupby for the current log as I go through each file, something like...

```
DF[DF['Iteration'] == CURRENTLOG_ID and DF['Feature Enabled'] == 1].groupby([’Feature Active'])[['Value1','Value2']].mean()
```

This would help me plot into Excel after each log as I go along and process a directory of logs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use multiple conditions you need to use bit-wise `&` and not `and`, also you need to enclose the conditions in parentheses due to operator precedence:

```
DF[(DF['Iteration'] == CURRENTLOG_ID) & (DF['Feature Enabled'] == 1)].groupby([’Feature Active'])[['Value1','Value2']].mean()
```

should work

Comment: Thanks EdChum...again :), I was kind of on the right road, but had some brackets out of place.

Comment: No worries, remember you can't use `and`, `or` and `not` when comparing arrays, you have to use `&`, `|` and `~` respectively and enclose in parentheses

Comment: Thanks for that, good advice. I'm slowly climbing the Python learning ladder after reaching a basic level plateau, so then I decide to look into Pandas!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [masks](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html).

```
mask_A  = DF['Feature Enabled'] == 1
mask_B  = DF['Iteration'] == CURRENTLOG_ID

subset = DF[mask_A & mask_B].groupby(...).mean()
```

Comment: I think you would still need to enclose the mask conditions in parentheses `()`

Comment: Thanks alec_djinn, I got your solution to work, but went with EdChums solution in the end as it fitted my original plan.  But thanks for highlighting masks this will come in useful.